# Publishing play module to internal maven repository

Tags: playframework, nexus

I can build a Play framework module locally and use it locally, but how can I publish it to an internal (Nexus) Maven repository (not the public Play repository) so that Play will be able to find it?

Comment: Unfortunately, Play uses Ivy (which is Maven-compatible) to download ordinary library dependencies, but not to download Play modules. For that it uses its own home-grown python code, which is not Maven-compatible.

Comment: Ah, no, that's the old mechanism. `play dependencies` should work, but for some reason it fails to install the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there's a [whole bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321241/how-to-use-play-with-custom-modules-and-continuous-integration/8324943#8324943) of different solutions to this. There's even a hint tucked away in the Play documentation, but it's reportedly slightly incorrect.

The solution I ended up using was adding a publish task to `build.xml` which uses ivy, and writing an `ivy.xml` file that set the artifact file type to `bundle` and the file extension to `zip`.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get a play 2.0 module building to a private maven server (Artificatory in my case) using the following config in project/Build.scala:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    /* Stuff about your app (version,name etc) and dependencies */


    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
          organization := "org.myorg"
    ).settings(
          publishTo := Some("My Realm" at "https://myserver.com/libs-release-local")
    ).settings(
          credentials += Credentials("My Realm", "myserver.com", "username", "password")
    )
}
```

Then typing

> play publish

In the project dir

**Edit**

for Play 2.3, add following to **build.sbt**

```
resolvers += "My Server" at "https://myserver.com/libs-release-local"

credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "myserver.com", "username", "password")
```

Then issue

> sbt publish

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Play framework myself, but normally you have two options. Does Play contain its own Maven build? If so, you can configure distribution management settings to the Play framework's pom.xml and just use "mvn deploy". Just configure Nexus like explained in the  following maven deploy plugin doc:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

If there's no Maven build for Play framework, you can use the "deploy:deploy-file" target for the jars you want to deploy manually to Nexus.

I remember it's a bit tricky at first to get all the necessary parameters for the deploy-file command. Be patient :)

Comment: This doesn't work with ivy resolving. Probably would work with an  entry in `dependencies.yml`, but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 0):

In a script you can use this command to push an artifact to a nexus repository, the user must have the right to push artifacts on nexus

```
curl --request POST --user user:passwd http://mynexus/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/myorg/$APPLICATION/$VERSION/$APPLICATION-$VERSION.zip -F "file=@dist/$APPLICATION-$VERSION.zip"  --verbose
```

Comment: That doesn't create a pom file though does it?

Comment: no, it just upload the module zip file thus play can download it when you use play deps if you correctly configure your local repository in your dependencies.yml

Comment: And how do you do that? According to a comment on the documentation page, the example given there doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321241/how-to-use-play-with-custom-modules-and-continuous-integration/8324943#8324943